# Number only Appendix in Article

Tags: appendices

I am using a customized style for my article, where section is the top header, and no numbering is made for sections, subsections...etc

I would like to keep it as it is, but, use an alphabetical numbering for my appendix.

Does anyone have a idea?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,Arial,9pt]{sae} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}%5,page
\begin{document} 

kjasww
\section{section}

\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
%\begin{appendices}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix}
\lipsum[1]
\end{appendices}
```

The style file can be found [here](https://www.writelatex.com/templates/template-for-writing-an-sae-technical-paper/xqdrgrvvcgvz#.U_3VC26Gcng);

Comment: Without an MWE it will be very difficult to answer that question, but assuming that your style is properly implemented (and its surely based on something, I guess?), using `\appendix` should automatically achieve what you want?

Comment: @Hackbard_C  Please check the edit, I just added a MWE

Comment: The `sae` document class has the instruction `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}`. This suppresses all sectioning headers as low as `part` (which has level `-1`). To (re-)enable the numbering of *section*-level headers (whose level is `1`), you need to provide the instruction `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` along with `\appendix`.

Comment: Solves my problem @Mico  thanks. can you add your comment as an answer so I change the post to `[answered]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sae` document class contains the instruction

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
```

This instruction suppresses the numbering of all sectioning headers as low as `part`, which has level `-1`. The level of `chapter` is `0`, that of `section` is `1`, `subsection` is `2`, etc.

To (re-)enable the numbering of section-level headers, you therefore need to provide the instruction

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

along with `\appendix`.